# EF6 Code first without Unit of work.Alternative to Repository pattern sample wanted

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am not an Orm fan at all and usually I use ado.net directly as performance is a  must in many of my projects.
I want to use EF6 in one project and I want to understand what the best practices are.

UnitOfWork

in my view from the reading (rob conery etc..) seems plain wrong and an overkill.
I have not found 1 decent example where unit of work is not used.
I want to keep all the data access in 1 dll.
If repositories is not the way to do it how do you do it?I need an example i can download.

My Solution will be composed of the following dlls:

```
MyCompany.Data (Reference MyCompany.Domain)

MyCompany.Domain 

MyCompany.Services (Reference MyCompany.Data)

MyCompany.Web (Not to reference MyCompany.Data)

MyCompany.Win (Not to reference MyCompany.Data)
```

Also

WinUI and Web Projects should not reference (Data.dll)

```
Call me old school but it seems plain wrong to have the UI reference the   dal.

MyCompany.Web CompositionRoot should only inject the services Interfaces    
not reference MyCompany.Data
```

MyCompany.Services
    calls the Dal.

Has anybody got a link of sample implementation of how to use EF without repositories in an isolated dll?

many thanks

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem. Call MyCompany.Data from MyCompany.Services, why MyCompany.Win or Web must access .Data at all?

Comment: Problem is that it seems that UOW is a complete waste of time and abstraction upon abstraction and cannot find an alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand you don't want to use Unit Of Work pattern which is assumed by Entity Framework context. However, what's wrong with this approach for example:

```
// in .Services or .Data, in repository class
public Item GetItem(long id) {
    using (var ctx = new MyEfContext()) {
        return ctx.Items.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ItemID == id);
    }
}
```

Here, context (so, unit of work) is not leaked outside repository. You can use same approach with updates and deletes by attaching item to new context you create in that update\delete method. Then you only need to ensure that you use POCO entities in separate dll (or better code-first approach), so that you can safely reference dll with your (plain) data items. Alternatively, you can map database entities (i.e. Item) to another plain class, before passing that to client.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx)

> A DbContext instance represents a combination of the Unit Of Work and
>   Repository patterns such that it can be used to query from a database
>   and group together changes that will then be written back to the store
>   as a unit.

So you cannot use Entity Framework and avoid the UOW pattern altogether. But you do not have to create your own Unit Of Work classes and Repositories if you don't want to. Just use `DbContext` and `DbSet` classes straight out of the box.

Lots of examples of how to do that at [Get Started with Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907)

Comment: Hi  thanks for your reply Colin.Those examples on MSDN are pathetic.Those are to explain a concept not how to structure a solution.Reading a bit more and googling a bit more it looks like more of a CORS implementation.I have used many times without UOW but doing "Using var cxt=new Context(conn){} etc.. I am looking how the dlls all fits together